# count all comment letters in javascript on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

**Question Description:**
Permission to ask, How do I create a function to calculate the total comments that exist, including all comment replies. Based on the data below using javascript, the total comments are 7 comments.

[image]

```
const comments = [
{
commentId: 1,
commentContent: 'Cry',
replies: [
{
commentId: 11,
commentContent: 'Cry too',
replies: [
{
commentId: 111,
commentContent: 'Cry too Cry too'
},
{
commentId: 112,
commentContent: 'Cry too Cry too Cry'
}
]
},
{
commentId: 12,
commentContent: 'Cry too',
replies: [
{
commentId: 121,
commentContent: 'Cry too Cry too'
}
]
}
]
},
{
commentId: 2,
commentContent: 'Cry'
}
]
```

Comment: And where did you get stuck? What have you tried (show your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code, in your question and explain what went wrong, and in what way)?

Comment: _"calculate the total comments that exist"_ - `comments` is an array. If you don't know how to determine the number of elements that are in an array (its "length" so to speak) you should definitely get (another) JS tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it

```js
const countComments = (data) => data.reduce((res, d) => {
   if(!d.replies){
    return res + d.commentContent.length
  }
  return res + d.commentContent.length + countComments(d.replies)
}, 0)


const comments = [{
    commentId: 1,
    commentContent: 'Cry',
    replies: [{
        commentId: 11,
        commentContent: 'Cry too',
        replies: [{
            commentId: 111,
            commentContent: 'Cry too Cry too'
          },
          {
            commentId: 112,
            commentContent: 'Cry too Cry too Cry'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        commentId: 12,
        commentContent: 'Cry too',
        replies: [{
          commentId: 121,
          commentContent: 'Cry too Cry too'
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    commentId: 2,
    commentContent: 'Cry'
  }
]



console.log(countComments(comments))
```

Comment: thank you in advance sir already want to take the time to respond to my question, but sorry, I mean how to calculate the total character of the comment, sorry my mistake in giving the question

Comment: I'm glad. Don't forget to accept the answer